# Change iapp icon, background,

Tags: themes, splash-screen, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm very new to NativeScript. I started to create an app to get more familiar with nativeScript. I use the hello world example (tns create myApp --ng).

Now I am at the point where I want to change the icon of my app nd also the background, splash-screen etc.

Can somebody tell me please how I got this managed? I read the docs but I don't really understand what I should do. I also try to replace the png's in the App_Resources//... but every time I type tns emulate  the png got replaced.

Comment: Your question is too broad - I recommend that you pass the tutorial apps where the basic scenarios (working with images, elements, navigation, bindings) are covered. As for the splash screens there are extended articles on taht toopi c in the documentation - here is the one for Android https://docs.nativescript.org/publishing/creating-launch-screens-android

Comment: Tutorial for NativeScript + Angular2 https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-0.html

Comment: Tutorial for core NativeScript https://docs.nativescript.org/tutorial/chapter-0

Comment: I was ill the last couple days... Thank you very much for the answer.. I will have a look to it!